# How to create shared image based off existing VM in Azure?

Tags: azure, image, terraform, virtual-machine

I have an existing Virtual Machine running in Azure that has customised software installed. I want to use Terraform to create an image of this virtual machine and store it in an image gallery. The problem is, I dont understand how Terraform uniquely identifies the virtual machine in question.

Currently, I have the following:

```
// Get VM I want to create an image for (how can I use this as the image reference?)
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
}

resource "azurerm_shared_image_gallery" "example" {
  name                = "example_image_gallery"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  description         = "Shared images and things."

}

resource "azurerm_shared_image" "example" {
  name                = "my-image"
  gallery_name        = azurerm_shared_image_gallery.example.name
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
  location            = "australiacentral"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  identifier {
    publisher = "teradata"
    offer     = "vantage-teradata-viewpoint"
    sku       = "teradata-viewpoint-single-system-hourly-new"
  }

  specialized = true
}
```

As far as I can tell, Terraform can only create the image based on the `identifier` block. But this does not uniquely identify my virtual machine. Am I missing something obvious?

My goal is to perform the "Capture" operation that is available via the Azure Portal via Terraform. How do I specify my source VM?

Comment: No. the identifier block is required for a shared image but there doesn't appear to be a way to specify a source VM. Only "publisher", "offer" and "sku" are available.

Answer (score 0):

Through additional research, I found I needed an `azurerm_shared_image_version` resource. Here, I was able to reference my existing Virtual Machine via `managed_image_id`:

```
// Get clienttools VM information
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "test-virtual-machine"
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
}

resource "azurerm_shared_image_gallery" "example" {
  name                = "myGallery"
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
  location            = "australiacentral"
  description         = "Shared images and things."

}

resource "azurerm_shared_image" "example" {
  name                = "my-image"
  gallery_name        = azurerm_shared_image_gallery.example.name
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
  location            = "australiacentral"
  os_type             = "Windows"

  identifier {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-datacenter-gensecond"
  }

  // Set this as it defaults to V1
  hyper_v_generation = "V2"
  specialized        = true
}

resource "azurerm_shared_image_version" "example" {
  name                = "0.0.1"
  gallery_name        = azurerm_shared_image_gallery.example.name
  image_name          = azurerm_shared_image.example.name
  resource_group_name = "rg-example"
  location            = "australiacentral"
  managed_image_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id

  target_region {
    name                   = "australiacentral"
    regional_replica_count = 1
    storage_account_type   = "Standard_LRS"
  }
}
```